# How to dismiss programmatically created UIView when user taps on any part of iPhone screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I am working on an app where a popup view is created programatically. Now requirement is when user taps somewhere else than that popview, I want to remove that view from superview.

Below is my code for creating view

```
- (IBAction)Morebtn:(id)sender {
    UIView *cv = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 60, 100, 80)];
   UIButton *label1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-50,2, 200, 30)];
    [label1 setTitle: @"My Button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    label1.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI" size:12.0];
    [label1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cv addSubview:label1];

    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,20, 200, 30)];
    label2.text = @"Mark as unread";
    label2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI" size:12.0];
    [cv addSubview:label2]; //add label2 to your custom view

    [cv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:cv];
}
```

Here is my screen shot of view
[image]

Comment: Try this https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmenu

Comment: You will need some way of identifying the new view in order to remove it later.  So use an instance variable (my preferred method) or set the tag of the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare `UIView *cv` in globally

and `Remove` function just like

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[cv setHidden:YES];
[self.view.superview endEditing:YES];
}
```

**choice no 2**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView * cv;

 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// here add the view

 cv = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 60, 100, 80)];
UIButton *label1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-50,2, 200, 30)];
[label1 setTitle: @"My Button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
label1.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI" size:12.0];
[label1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cv addSubview:label1];

UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,20, 200, 30)];
label2.text = @"Mark as unread";
label2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI" size:12.0];
[cv addSubview:label2]; //add label2 to your custom view

[cv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

}
```

in your button action

```
- (IBAction)Morebtn:(id)sender {

   [self.view addSubview:cv];

}
```

Comment: just set frame globally >

Answer (score 1):

It works 100%

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
        [urView removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Comment: how can i get my view name CV as this view is not globally created

Comment: better you have to declare it globally

Comment: Not true.  Use an instance variable.  Do **not** declare it globally.

Comment: @rajeev - r u saw the image the view is appear in front of tableview

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

UIView* viewYouWishToObtain = [self hitTest:locationPoint withEvent:event];
 if ([viewYouWishToObtain isKindOfClass: [customView Class]])
    [customView removeFromSuperview];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you..

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

[cv removeFromSuperView];
```

// or

```
[cv setHidden:Yes];
}
```

Comment: `cv` is a local variable in a different method?!?

Comment: in here **[cv setHidden:Yes];** does not work, bz the ? add the view in button so **removeFromSuperView** only works

Comment: @ArvindKumarMobulous -- r u saw the image the view is appear in front of tableview

Comment: you just make cv as Global..then do this..It works fine

Answer (score 0):

its pretty simple, just create one method in your self UIViewController.
touchesBegan and write a method into that.
but before that make your Object cv global in your view

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [self.cv removeFromSuperview];
     self.cv=nil;
}
```